# Including distance in geo search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have implemented Elastic Search - Java API to search data based on the distance.

```
QueryBuilder geoQuery =  QueryBuilders.geoDistanceQuery("article_location.location").point(lat , lon).distance(5 , DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(geoQuery);
```

However, I would like to get distance in each result from input lat/lon. Is there any way to specify that?

I see in elastic DSL we can do it via `script_fields` but do not know how to get it via Java API.

```
"script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": "doc['latlong'].distanceInKm(lat, lon)"
    }
```

Im using

> elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.9.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java client also allows you to add script fields to your query, simply like this:

```
sourceBuilder.query(...);

// add lat/lon as parameters
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("lat", lat);
params.put("lon", lon);

// create the script
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "doc['latlong'].distanceInKm(params.lat, params.lon)", params);

// add the script field to the source query builder
sourceBuilder.scriptField("distance", script);
```

Comment: It worked !! Just that I had to use arcDistance instead of distanceInKm (it is deprecated seems). Also, included searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource(true); to retain original attributes.